# How can I make MS Exchange think that a samba PDC is running a version of windows later than Server 2003?

Tags: linux, exchange-2010, samba4

I'm busy migrating my Active Directory to a Linux server (Centos 7) running Sernet's enterprise samba packackes (Version 4.1.14-SerNet-RedHat-9.el7)

The Domain Controller seems to be working well for all authentication, except Exchange.  The Informatino Store starts, then hangs on "Starting".

The event log shows the following warning:

```
Process STORE.EXE (PID=3100). The domain controller pdc.*.*.*is running 
Windows (Unknown Operating System) (Unknown Service Pack). 
Exchange Active Directory Provider requires that domain controllers are running 
Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 or later versions of Windows.
```

How can I configure Samba to trick Exchange into thinking this server meets its requirements?

P.S.  I'm running Exchange 2010

Comment: I don't believe you can because Exchange relies on a lot of Active Directory things that Sernet won't provide properly. I really advise against this.

Comment: There are some times where "near enough" just isn't good enough. This is one of those times.

Comment: The SAMBA [project status page](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba/Status) shows Exchange support as being in development, noting it is "very much a work in progress" - although the [page history](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php?title=Samba/Status&action=history) suggests that line hasn't been updated in 2 years.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to "Raise domain functional level"?

By default samba4 look like "Windows server 2003"

Answer (score 0):

To just fake a Windows Operating System signature, find the computer account of your samba DC. In a properly configured Directory you would find this at `OU=Domain Controllers,DC=mydomain,DC=myforest,DC=mytld`. Edit the following attributes:

- operatingSystem
- operatingSystemServicePack
- operatingSystemServicePackLevel

You are going to run into further trouble when the Exchange prep tools start probing into what's OS level your infrastructure is really running on.

According to the [Active Directory Technical Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223122.aspx), this information is stored on the `nTDSDSA` object that represents the Directory Service Agent on each DC, in the Configuration NC.

The attribute in question is [`msDS-Behavior-Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223741.aspx), and the docs provide a list of possible values and the corresponding OS levels.

I really don't believe this is feasible, but if you want to try, you'll probably have to emulate Windows behavior in a number of other places as well.

The `msDS-Behavior-Version` attribute is used to store the Forest Functional Level on the forest `crossRefContainer` (found in `CN=Partitions,CN=Configurations,DC=myforest,DC=tld`) and the Domain Functional Level on the Domain NC root object of each domain

There are some constraints as to which versions can coexist:

- The Domain Functional Level of each domain cannot exceed that of the "oldest" DC in that domain
- The Forest Functional Level cannot exceed that of the "oldest" Domain

To get a better understanding of what Exchange is "expecting", you might want to read through [this chapter about special objects and behaviors in an Active Directory forest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223524.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Exchange does lots of checks.  One very specific check is looking at the Schema version (i.e.: in the Schema partition).  Out of interest, what's the rationale behind moving to Samba-based DCs?

Comment: Saving a hell of a lot of money ?